# Tables Generated Throug Stargazer Showing Errors

Tags: math-mode, longtable, threeparttable, threeparttablex

I am using stargazer package to produce some tables of regression. However, the table is long table and I am customizing the output of the stargazer to make adjustment of the long table. The preamble is given below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[tc]{titlepic}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Soperator}{\mathit{S}}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm }
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,longtable,tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,ragged2e,ltxtable,pdflscape,filecontents}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}% <-- added
\usepackage{ltablex}% <-- added
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added
\usepackage[flushleft, online]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\title{A Test Paper}
    \date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle{}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
    \begin{TableNotes}[para]%
    \footnotesize
    \item[]This is ordinary least square.
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
    \caption{OLS} 
    \label{tab1}\\ 
        \insertTableNotes\\
    \toprule
    \midrule
    {\bfseries{}}   &{\bfseries(1)} & {\bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} & {\bfseries(4)} \\
    \endfirsthead
    \caption{-- continued from previous page}\\
    \toprule
    & {\bfseries(1)} & {\bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} & {\bfseries(4)}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize Continued on next page} \\
    \endfoot
    \addlinespace       
    \endlastfoot %
    \midrule 
    treat1SEC & 0.083^{***} & 0.080^{***} & 0.071^{***} & 0.070^{***} \\ 
        & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.016) & (0.015) \\ 
        treat1CB & -0.002 & 0.007 & -0.001 & 0.002 \\ 
        & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.016) & (0.015) \\ 
        tfcSEC & -0.151^{***} & -0.157^{***} & -0.139^{***} & -0.126^{***} \\ 
        & (0.017) & (0.017) & (0.023) & (0.022) \\ 
        tfcCB & -0.006 & -0.028 & -0.011 & -0.012 \\ 
        & (0.017) & (0.018) & (0.023) & (0.022) \\ 
        Xtrwata &  & -0.165^{***} & -0.162^{***} & 0.278^{***} \\ 
        &  & (0.045) & (0.045) & (0.068) \\ 
        Xtllpr &  & 2.825^{***} & 2.819^{***} & 4.304^{***} \\ 
        &  & (0.732) & (0.732) & (0.785) \\ 
        Xtncor &  & -2.079^{**} & -2.126^{***} & -2.988^{***} \\ 
        &  & (0.816) & (0.817) & (0.837) \\ 
        Xtroa &  & 0.594 & 0.469 & 2.815^{***} \\ 
        &  & (0.853) & (0.860) & (0.931) \\ 
        Xter &  & 0.778^{***} & 0.801^{***} & 0.443^{*} \\ 
        &  & (0.178) & (0.179) & (0.241) \\ 
        Xtidis &  & 0.098^{**} & 0.098^{**} & 0.135^{***} \\ 
        &  & (0.039) & (0.039) & (0.042) \\ 
        Xtninor &  & 0.002 & 0.001 & 0.011^{*} \\ 
        &  & (0.006) & (0.006) & (0.006) \\ 
        Xtlr &  & 0.165^{***} & 0.167^{***} & -0.063 \\ 
        &  & (0.047) & (0.047) & (0.062) \\ 
        Xtag &  & -0.014 & -0.015 & 0.014 \\ 
        &  & (0.028) & (0.028) & (0.029) \\ 
        Xtrep &  & -0.054^{**} & -0.051^{**} & -0.011 \\ 
        &  & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.025) \\ 
        fc &  &  & -0.019 & 0.060 \\ 
        &  &  & (0.016) & (0.151) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_rwata\_1 &  &  &  & -0.602^{***} \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.082) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_llpr\_1 &  &  &  & -1.179 \\ 
        &  &  &  & (1.055) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_ncor\_1 &  &  &  & 0.101 \\ 
        &  &  &  & (1.002) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_roa\_1 &  &  &  & -3.137^{**} \\ 
        &  &  &  & (1.394) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_er\_1 &  &  &  & 0.404 \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.302) \\ 

        Xfc\_1fc\_idis\_1 &  &  &  & -0.036 \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.068) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_ninor\_1 &  &  &  & 0.026^{**} \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.012) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_size\_1 &  &  &  & 0.006 \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.005) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_lr\_1 &  &  &  & 0.168^{*} \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.093) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_ag\_1 &  &  &  & -0.055 \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.035) \\ 
        Constant & -0.013^{*} & -0.112 & -0.114 & -0.152 \\ 
        & (0.008) & (0.080) & (0.080) & (0.095) \\ 
        \midrule
        Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,620} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,620} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,620} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,620} \\ 
        R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.050} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.112} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.112} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.196} \\ 
        Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.048} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.099} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.099} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.176} \\ 
        Residual Std. Error & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.008} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.008} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.008} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.007} \\ 
        F Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{21.410$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.112$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.777$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.848$^{***}$} \\ 
        \bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{c}{*\textit{p} < 0.1; **\textit{p} < 0.05; ***\textit{p} < 0.01} \\
\end{longtable}% 
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

However, I get the error:

```
Command \bfseries invalid in math mode. ...bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} & {\bfseries
```

Comment: The error message is caused by the use of `\bfseries` insid of `dcolumn`'s `D` column type. Either use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries(1)}` instead or switch to the `S` column type from the `siunitx` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two versions using either `dcolumn` or `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm }

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[flushleft, online]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
    \begin{TableNotes}[para]%
    \footnotesize
    \item[]This is ordinary least square.
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
    \caption{OLS} 
    \label{tab1}\\ 
        \insertTableNotes\\
    \toprule
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries{}}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries(2)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries(4)} \\
    \endfirsthead
    \caption{-- continued from previous page}\\
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries(2)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries(4)}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize Continued on next page} \\
    \endfoot
    \addlinespace       
    \endlastfoot %
    \midrule 
    treat1SEC & 0.083^{***} & 0.080^{***} & 0.071^{***} & 0.070^{***} \\ 
        & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.016) & (0.015) \\ 
        treat1CB & -0.002 & 0.007 & -0.001 & 0.002 \\ 
        & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.016) & (0.015) \\ 
        tfcSEC & -0.151^{***} & -0.157^{***} & -0.139^{***} & -0.126^{***} \\ 
        & (0.017) & (0.017) & (0.023) & (0.022) \\ 
        tfcCB & -0.006 & -0.028 & -0.011 & -0.012 \\ 
        & (0.017) & (0.018) & (0.023) & (0.022) \\ 
        Xtrwata &  & -0.165^{***} & -0.162^{***} & 0.278^{***} \\ 
        &  & (0.045) & (0.045) & (0.068) \\ 
        Xtllpr &  & 2.825^{***} & 2.819^{***} & 4.304^{***} \\ 
        &  & (0.732) & (0.732) & (0.785) \\ 
        Xtncor &  & -2.079^{**} & -2.126^{***} & -2.988^{***} \\ 
        &  & (0.816) & (0.817) & (0.837) \\ 
        Xtroa &  & 0.594 & 0.469 & 2.815^{***} \\ 
        &  & (0.853) & (0.860) & (0.931) \\ 
        Xter &  & 0.778^{***} & 0.801^{***} & 0.443^{*} \\ 
        &  & (0.178) & (0.179) & (0.241) \\ 
        Xtidis &  & 0.098^{**} & 0.098^{**} & 0.135^{***} \\ 
        &  & (0.039) & (0.039) & (0.042) \\ 
        Xtninor &  & 0.002 & 0.001 & 0.011^{*} \\ 
        &  & (0.006) & (0.006) & (0.006) \\ 
        Xtlr &  & 0.165^{***} & 0.167^{***} & -0.063 \\ 
        &  & (0.047) & (0.047) & (0.062) \\ 
        Xtag &  & -0.014 & -0.015 & 0.014 \\ 
        &  & (0.028) & (0.028) & (0.029) \\ 
        Xtrep &  & -0.054^{**} & -0.051^{**} & -0.011 \\ 
        &  & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.025) \\ 
        fc &  &  & -0.019 & 0.060 \\ 
        &  &  & (0.016) & (0.151) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_rwata\_1 &  &  &  & -0.602^{***} \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.082) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_llpr\_1 &  &  &  & -1.179 \\ 
        &  &  &  & (1.055) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_ncor\_1 &  &  &  & 0.101 \\ 
        &  &  &  & (1.002) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_roa\_1 &  &  &  & -3.137^{**} \\ 
        &  &  &  & (1.394) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_er\_1 &  &  &  & 0.404 \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.302) \\ 

        Xfc\_1fc\_idis\_1 &  &  &  & -0.036 \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.068) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_ninor\_1 &  &  &  & 0.026^{**} \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.012) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_size\_1 &  &  &  & 0.006 \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.005) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_lr\_1 &  &  &  & 0.168^{*} \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.093) \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_ag\_1 &  &  &  & -0.055 \\ 
        &  &  &  & (0.035) \\ 
        Constant & -0.013^{*} & -0.112 & -0.114 & -0.152 \\ 
        & (0.008) & (0.080) & (0.080) & (0.095) \\ 
        \midrule
        Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,620} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,620} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,620} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,620} \\ 
        R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.050} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.112} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.112} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.196} \\ 
        Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.048} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.099} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.099} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.176} \\ 
        Residual Std. Error & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.008} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.008} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.008} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.007} \\ 
        F Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{21.410$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.112$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.777$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.848$^{***}$} \\ 
        \bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{c}{*\textit{p} < 0.1; **\textit{p} < 0.05; ***\textit{p} < 0.01} \\
\end{longtable}% 
\end{ThreePartTable}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{TableNotes}[para]%
    \footnotesize
    \item[]This is ordinary least square.
\end{TableNotes}

\sisetup{
        table-space-text-pre={(},
         table-space-text-post={***},
         input-open-uncertainty = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
         table-format=-1.4,
         table-text-alignment=right,
         table-align-text-pre = false,
         table-align-text-post = false
        } 
\begin{longtable}{lSSSS }
    \caption{OLS} 
    \label{tab1}\\ 
        \insertTableNotes\\
    \toprule
    & {\bfseries(1)} & {\bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} & {\bfseries(4)}\\
    \endfirsthead
    \caption{-- continued from previous page}\\
    \toprule
    & {\bfseries(1)} & {\bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} & {\bfseries(4)}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize Continued on next page} \\
    \endfoot
    \addlinespace       
    \endlastfoot %
    \midrule 
        treat1SEC           & 0.083{***}    & 0.080{***}   & 0.071{***}  & 0.070{***}    \\ 
                            & (0.014)       & (0.014)      & (0.016)      & (0.015)      \\ 
        treat1CB            & -0.002        & 0.007        & -0.001       & 0.002        \\ 
                            & (0.014)       & (0.014)      & (0.016)      & (0.015)      \\ 
        tfcSEC              & -0.151{***}   & -0.157{***}  & -0.139{***}  & -0.126{***}  \\ 
                            & (0.017)       & (0.017)      & (0.023)      & (0.022)      \\ 
        tfcCB               & -0.006        & -0.028       & -0.011       & -0.012       \\ 
                            & (0.017)       & (0.018)      & (0.023)      & (0.022)      \\ 
        Xtrwata             &               & -0.165{***}  & -0.162{***}  & 0.278{***}   \\ 
                            &               & (0.045)      & (0.045)      & (0.068)      \\ 
        Xtllpr              &               & 2.825{***}   & 2.819{***}   & 4.304{***}   \\ 
                            &               & (0.732)      & (0.732)      & (0.785)      \\ 
        Xtncor              &               & -2.079{**}   & -2.126{***}  & -2.988{***}  \\ 
                            &               & (0.816)      & (0.817)      & (0.837)      \\ 
        Xtroa               &               & 0.594        & 0.469        & 2.815{***}   \\ 
                            &               & (0.853)      & (0.860)      & (0.931)      \\ 
        Xter                &               & 0.778{***}   & 0.801{***}   & 0.443{*}     \\ 
                            &               & (0.178)      & (0.179)      & (0.241)      \\ 
        Xtidis              &               & 0.098{**}    & 0.098{**}    & 0.135{***}   \\ 
                            &               & (0.039)      & (0.039)      & (0.042)      \\ 
        Xtninor             &               & 0.002        & 0.001        & 0.011{*}     \\ 
                            &               & (0.006)      & (0.006)      & (0.006)      \\ 
        Xtlr                &               & 0.165{***}   & 0.167{***}   & -0.063       \\ 
                            &               & (0.047)      & (0.047)      & (0.062)      \\ 
        Xtag                &               & -0.014       & -0.015       & 0.014        \\ 
                            &               & (0.028)      & (0.028)      & (0.029)      \\ 
        Xtrep               &               & -0.054{**}   & -0.051{**}   & -0.011       \\ 
                            &               & (0.026)      & (0.026)      & (0.025)      \\ 
        fc                  &               &              & -0.019       & 0.060        \\ 
                            &               &              & (0.016)      & (0.151)      \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_rwata\_1  &               &              &              & -0.602{***}  \\ 
                            &               &              &              & (0.082)      \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_llpr\_1   &               &              &              & -1.179       \\ 
                            &               &              &              & (1.055)      \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_ncor\_1   &               &              &              & 0.101        \\ 
                            &               &              &              & (1.002)      \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_roa\_1    &               &              &              & -3.137{**}   \\ 
                            &               &              &              & (1.394)      \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_er\_1     &               &              &              & 0.404        \\ 
                            &               &              &              & (0.302)      \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_idis\_1   &               &              &              & -0.036       \\ 
                            &               &              &              & (0.068)      \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_ninor\_1  &               &              &              & 0.026{**}    \\ 
                            &               &              &              & (0.012)      \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_size\_1   &               &              &              & 0.006        \\ 
                            &               &              &              & (0.005)      \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_lr\_1     &               &              &              & 0.168{*}     \\ 
                            &               &              &              & (0.093)      \\ 
        Xfc\_1fc\_ag\_1     &               &              &              & -0.055       \\ 
                            &               &              &              & (0.035)      \\ 
        Constant            & -0.013{*}     & -0.112       & -0.114       & -0.152       \\ 
                            & (0.008)       & (0.080)      & (0.080)      & (0.095)      \\ 
        \midrule
        Observations        & {1,620}       & {1,620}      & {1,620}      &{1,620}       \\ 
        R$^{2}$             & {0.050}       & {0.112}      & {0.112}      & {0.196}      \\ 
        Adjusted R$^{2}$    & {0.048}       & {0.099}      & {0.099}      & {0.176}      \\ 
        Residual Std. Error & {0.008}       & {0.008}      & {0.008}      & {0.007}      \\ 
        F Statistic         & {21.410{***}} & {9.112{***}} & {8.777{***}} & {9.848{***}} \\ 
        \bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{c}{*\textit{p} < 0.1; **\textit{p} < 0.05; ***\textit{p} < 0.01}         \\
\end{longtable}% 
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```